# Is there a way to load a button's onClickListener if it's not already being shown?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a back button for a different page than the originally loaded one but unless the button is already loaded, you can't do anything with it. How do I load a button once a certain page is loaded, and unload it when the view is switched?

I've already tried if statements and while loops but if statements do nothing and while loops prevent the page from loading.

These are what the if statements look like:

```
if (view == 1) {
   formulas.setOnClickListener { 
      setContentView(activity_main)
      view = 2
   }
}

if (view == 2) {
   back.setOnClickListener { 
      setContentView(formulas_main)
      view = 1
   }
}
```

and the while loops look like:

```
while (view == 1) {
   formulas.setOnClickListener {
      setContentView(activity_main)
      view = 2
   }
}

while (view == 2) {
   back.setOnClickListener {
      setContentView(formulas_main)
      view = 1
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by load the button? Make the button visible? What's your goal here? Do you want the onClickListener to behave differently for the same button depending on the view change?

Comment: I meant load the button's onClickListener with it being on a separate view because if you try to set onClickListener for a button not in the current view, it gives an error saying you tried changing a null value